# Parsing nested XML files using SAX API's

Tags: python, xml, parsing, memory

SAX style parsing using Pythons `xml.sax` is a common way to parse huge XML files but is there any way to parse a nested XML using that library?
I have a solution using the `ElementTree` but unfortunately my PC runs out of RAM. The file I'm parsing is 100GB.

A nested XML could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>
        <header> Hello Sweetie </header>
        <subheader> Why you like this? </subheader>
      </title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>
        <euro> 9.99 </euro>
        <krone>
            <sek> 70 </sek>
            <dkk> 77 </dkk>
        </krone>
      </price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I need every xml-tag out and the corresponding text and put in into a table or dictionary.

Comment: All XML is surely nested in this sense, and the SAX interface is designed to handle it. What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: what is the currency, if you have only price? How looks like your code so fare? –

Comment: Only way I've found to successfully parse huge xml is to use XmlReader which is available in Powershell and c#.